# Aspx C# Generate .cs file from EDMX

Tags: c#, asp.net

Code generated

```
public partial class Books
{

    public long productId { get; set; }

    public string bookName { get; set; }
```

Code that I need

```
public partial class Books: Product
{
    public string bookName { get; set; }
```

How can i get like the second code??

Comment: Why do you need the second one? And you probably won't get it since the classes are probably auto generated. So why not create your own class and inherit from Book if  you need it?

Comment: I need it to then make this comparation (product is Books)

Comment: Maybe editing the edmx?

Comment: I have the tables book and product created on my DB, how do I tell to the edmx that I want Bike to inherit from Product?

Comment: Yep modifing the edmx relationship just manualy made Book heredit from Product